# Where is Trash Bin in Ubuntu 11.10 with Gnome Shell?

Tags: 11.10, gnome, trash

I am using Ubuntu 11.10 with Gnome Classic shell. How can I open Trash Bin?

Comment: Have a look at this - it has instructions on how to add the trash bin (wastebasket) to the classic panel.  http://askubuntu.com/questions/58172/how-to-revert-to-gnome-classic

Comment: On Gnome 2 it was `~/.local/share/Trash/`

Comment: @MartinThoma Seems to be unchanged in Gnome3, at least on my Debian 8 machine.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Open a folder (any folder). In the sidebar, you'll see an entry for the trash. That's it.

Comment: You can also add a trash icon to the top panel with this extension: https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/48/trash/

Answer (score 4):

`sudo apt-get install gnome-tweak-tool`

Install that. Go to Applications > Other > Advanced

You can put a trash can and change your font.

PS: reprinted from http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1860565

Answer (score 2):

Just install the `gnome-tweak-tool`, start it via Alt-F2 and you can add the Trash icon (and others) to your desktop.